# Are there more casual ways to say "flowery speech/language" aside from 美辞麗句?

Tags: word-choice

I came across a situation where I wanted to use a phrase like "flowery language" or "flowery speech", I looked it up and found 美{び}辞{じ} online.

-

#### I did a little research:

Initially I looked for the root in another dictionary. I found 美{び}辞{じ}麗{れい}句{く}. I asked a Japanese friend and they said they had never heard of this word nor the first part of the word.

I also searched another dictionary and came back with 美{び}文{ぶん} and 華{か}言{げん} as viable options. I'm not sure about 美文 but with 華言 that same friend they had seen or used it before.

Which would be the best way to convey "flowery speech/language" while not becoming to complex for everyday conversation or business talk?

Comment: 美文体 and 華やかな（言葉） might be suitable alternatives.

Comment: 美辞麗句 may indicate "flowery words", but more likely to mean "ear-pleasing" or "fine-sounding".

Comment: @broccoliforest Oh okay, I see. I guess I might need to clarify my question a little.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I do wonder how old your Japanese friend is, but you do not have to answer.

While 「美辞麗句」 may not be an everyday kind of word, I would imagine that the majority of the adult native speakers would know what it meant.

More informal phrases that carry basically the same meaning as 「美辞麗句」 include:

・「飾{かざ}った言葉」、「飾り立てた言葉」

・「耳触{みみざわ}りの良い（言い回{まわ}し or 文句{もんく}）」

・「ごてごてした言葉」

etc.

Comment: She is in her late 20's

Comment: Would explaining something that is too flowery in a way that it becomes negative yield different words in this case?